# Update MySQL timestamp even if row data is unchanged

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script that imports sql scripts into a MySQL 5 database.
Each script contains nothing but `UPDATE` statements that each update 1 row in a table (MyISAM).

If a row has not been inside one of these scripts for 2 days it must be deleted. The table has a timestamp column. However when the UPDATE statement doesn't change any columns the timestamp is not updated and I have no way of telling wether the row was in the import file or not.
Is there a way to force this timestamp update, even if no data changes?

**EDIT:**
Further clarification.

The importfiles are gzipped files that contain about 450.000 rows, each row is 1 UPDATE statement.

Here's the PHP function that handles the import files:

```
private function ImportFile($filename) {
    $importfile = gzopen($filename, "r");
    if (!$importfile) {
        throw new Exception("Could not open Gzip file " . $filename);
    }

    while (!gzeof($importfile)) {
        $line = gzgets($importfile, 4096);
        if (!$line) {
            throw new Exception("Error reading line number $line Gzip file $filename");
        }

        if (strlen(trim($line)) > 0) {
            $this->DB->Query($line);
        }
    }

    gzclose($importfile);
}
```

Comment: Hi, i don't really understand you problem, can you clarify it with some code, a sample of the UPDATE files or something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could simply have an update for all the fields that where not updated, for instance:

```
UPDATE mytable SET timestamp=NOW() WHERE id IN (1, 5, 6, ...);
```

Comment: Most of these import files update around 450.000 rows, and I would have to parse each update statement to get the primary key out of it. I was hoping there would be an easier way.

Comment: I don't know if you can edit your scripts but you could force each UPDATE statement to have a SET timestamp=NOW().

Comment: It's indeed something to think about, The application that creates the scripts is an old Powerbuilder 9 application. If we make the change there we'd have to deploy that to our clients. But maybe I can use that in the PHP script, add it to each line as it passes. If I resort to that i'll mark this answer as accepted

Comment: I would assume that setting the value to NOW() requires more processing than setting it to NULL.  I see that [MySQL docs suggest](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html) that you set it to NULL to have it update the timestamp.

Answer (score 6):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Similar to using NOW() - as long as a TIMESTAMP column doesn't allow NULL values you can force it to update by setting that column to NULL.

```
UPDATE mytable SET timestamp=NULL
```

Comment: Yes, I see that [MySQL docs suggest](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html), "you can initialize or update any TIMESTAMP column to the current date and time by assigning it a NULL value, unless it has been defined with the NULL attribute to permit NULL values."

Comment: If column type is DATETIME, setting value to NULL will set it to '0000-00-00 00:00:00' but setting it to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP works